# SharePoint Recurring Event Start Date

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer, power-automate

This one is driving me nuts, so I hope someone may be able to help.

Each recurring event will show the Start Time, when used in sorting and calculations, of the first recurring event. The End Time has the same issue and reflects the last scheduled recurrence.

I need to use the actual ever date. I am creating a flow to add the current day’s tasks from a SharePoint calendar into a Planner task plan. I want that flow to only pull the current day events from the calendar.

The tools I may use for this include SharePoint, SharePoint Designer, and flow.

Does anyone have many guidance in how I may be able to accomplish this?

Thank you in advance for taking the time to review my inquiry.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!!

Here are the steps I performed: 
1) In SharePoint, create a copy of the Current Events view
2) Open SharePoint Designer
3) Open the view created in #1
4) Navigate to the Query Where statement
5) Change the  towards the end of the date range overlap to

Before:

```
            <Where>
            <DateRangesOverlap>
                <FieldRef Name="EventDate"/>
                <FieldRef Name="EndDate"/>
                <FieldRef Name="RecurrenceID"/>
                <Value Type="DateTime">
                    <Now/>
                </Value>
            </DateRangesOverlap>
        </Where>
```

After:

```
            <Where>
            <DateRangesOverlap>
                <FieldRef Name="EventDate"/>
                <FieldRef Name="EndDate"/>
                <FieldRef Name="RecurrenceID"/>
                <Value Type="DateTime">
                    <Today/>
                </Value>
            </DateRangesOverlap>
        </Where>
```

This gave me the correct current day view that may now be leveraged in Flow.

Answer (score 0):

You can have my DLL for the fetching it with c# code. Kindly install the dll and use it in below manner.

https://github.com/shafeequealipt/Share-Point-Recurrance-event-splitter.

```
EventSplitter obj = new EventSplitter(); var x = 
obj.Execute(Site,
ListName, Username, Password, Convert.ToInt32(Hour));

Out_dataTable = x.Item3; 
Message = x.Item1;
Success = x.Item2;
```

Parameters

Site = Share point site URL, List Name = Share point List Name , Username = Username to access the site , Password = Password to access the site, Hours = Time to which you have to fetch details

Example: If we mention 9 in hours, the DLL will fetch details of all resources, which is available in calendar from current time to next 9 hours.

This may resolve your issue